# How to open a Google Sheets file and go immediately to the end of the file

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 100 lines.

Every time I open that file, I want to insert a row on the end of my table.

How can I jump to the last line of the table when I open the doc?

Because right now I have to scroll down in order to be able to insert a new line.

Comment: Would a key combination suffice? Ctrl+End should jump you to the end of the file.

Comment: @AlE.: Does Ctrl+End move to the last column also? I don't have a Windows box to test with, but on Mac, the corresponding shortcut (⌘+Fn+➔) moves to last row, last column.

Comment: @Vidar: Yeah, probably. (I don't have the ability to test it at the moment.) Fairly easily rectified by then hitting the `Home` key.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a trigger that runs every time your spreadsheet is opened.

Go to *Extensions → Apps Script* and paste the following:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == lastRow) {
    sheet.appendRow([""]);
  }
  lastRow = lastRow + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Click the *Save* button, then close the script editor, and the spreadsheet.

Now, open your spreadsheet again. Give it a couple of seconds, and you should see that a new row is inserted at the end of your sheet, and that that row is selected.

I have created [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RDeB6a0McNO90JitsSay-sVoApYTAoQWbCAp38sqgEs/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate - feel free to copy it (click *File → Copy*). You will need to run your own copy in order to see the script run successfully.

#### The script explained:

The `onOpen` function name has a special meaning. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen).
It takes a single argument, an [`Event` object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). Its `source` property is a reference to the spreadsheet being opened. With the spreadsheet, we can do [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getlastrow) to find the index of the last row *that has content*. [`getMaxRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows) gives us the max number of rows in the sheet, even empty ones. With that knowledge, we can see if the last row has content - if so, we append a new, empty row. Finally, we can create a [*range*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and call [`setActiveRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setactiverangerange) on it, to move to the last row.

---

If you just want to move to the last line, not inserting anything, the script can be simplified as this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Comment: Great answer @VidarS.Ramdal. How can I do the same when switching to an existing sheet?

Comment: @Hamideh There's no event triggered when switching between sheets in the same document, as I'm aware of. So this approach would not work in that case.

Comment: Use this for the last line with text 
```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var lastRow = Avals.filter(String).length+1;
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Google Sheets no longer has a Script Editor option under Tools. It now has the menu option Extension | Apps Scripts, so the answer needs updating.
This function can be put in the resulting window opened. 
I then tried deploying it as a WebApp but the cursor remains at the top of the spreadsheet when it's opened. How should it be deployed to work?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the additional problem that certain columns are populated with formulas all the way down, and you want to scroll to the first row that has non-formula data, here is an approach.  In this case column A has formulas all the way down, so I scroll to the first blank cell in column B in row 5 or below.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var spreadsheet = e.source;
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var row = 5;
    while (true) {
        var range = sheet.getRange("B" + row);
        if (!range.getValue()) {
            sheet.setActiveRange(range);
            return;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```

As the other answer indicates, you should open *Tools → Script editor*, paste in that function, name your "project", save, and reload the spreadsheet.